# Is it possible to get @Autowired to happen before @Factory method in TestNG?

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I am working on a test suite using WebDriver and TestNG.  The application under test has a "report menu" which is a set of links to a ton of different reports. The list of reports is dynamic based on a bunch of different variables. I'd like to create a @Factory which creates a distinct test case for each of these links. So far so good.

However, to discover the links, I need WebDriver initialized (to go to the page, and find all of the links), but that is happening via injection from Spring IOC, and the autowiring (using @Autowired) happens much later in the lifecycle of the test runner. All of the parameters used to construct the driver itself are also injected (base url, driver class, download directory etc), so it's not feasible in this case to create a WebDriver instance "by hand" - it has to be done via the Spring application context as configured using @ContextConfiguration annotation.

So is there a manual way to get the injection to happen this early in the lifecycle of the runner?

Answer (score 0):

My somewhat poor solution to this is:

Since the `@Factory` method runs really early, just have it return a pre-defined size array of some "empty" test cases.  Say the test is MyTest, just do:

```
@Factory
public Object[] factoryMethod() {
    Object[] tests = new MyTest[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        tests[i] = new MyTest();
    }
    return tests;
}
```

Have the test method, say `test()` inside `MyTest` run at priority=1.  Have a completely separate test method at priority=0, which goes to the "menu" page using the now-instantiated `WebDriver` object, find the links (hopefully less than 100 of them), and go "fill in" the missing parameters in the pre-created test instances.  Finally, when the `MyTest` instance's `test()` method gets called, if the parameters were not filled in, throw a `SkipException` to have that "extra" instance not do anything. A bit clunky, but working.

I'd downvote this answer based on the dirty feeling it gives me.